Can't find x86 .NET Framework when running unit tests with Github workflow
I have a strange issue where I have a GitHub workflow that builds our software and runs some unit tests successfully when it's all built as 'Any CPU' but i now have to build and test as x86. The main application builds successfully as 32 bit but the unit tests give an error:

When i run the unit tests I change the architecture to x86 with the --arch x86

I've done a bit of reading on this and it seems to be missing the .NET 7 x86 components.....but i've always assumed the .NET installation included all components for x86 and x64.
Some other information:

All tests run via the command line on my local machine work as
expected.
I'm using .NET 7 on the github runner.



The test project is setup as follows:



The runner is setup as a windows machine


Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated.
